# Null pointer exception on widgets from other layouts than main

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to add various fragments to an Action bar Activity.

Here is one of the fragments (nested inside the main activity):

```
public static class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static ScheduleFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        ScheduleFragment fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ScheduleFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And the respective xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And when I call

```
    titles.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView));
    titles.get(0).setText(R.string.Departure_Location);
```

from within the MainActivity class, I get Null pointer exception, and I'm guessing that's because R.id.textView is defined in the "schedule_layout.xml" and not in the "main_activity.xml".

Android studio checker finds the R.id.textView, even though I have no textView in the "main_activity.xml".

So how exactly can I sort this out?

Comment: Add the exception trace as well.

Comment: What is "titles" and where is it declared? Also please clarify what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: You need to include the block of code where the NPE occurs, in MainActivity.java

Comment: I added the exception trace.
I clarifies what is titles, and what I want to achieve is be able to use the textView from another xml file.

Comment: The NPE occurs when I call "titles.get(0).setText(R.string.Departure_Location);"

Comment: You can help yourself a lot if you learn how to run your app in debug mode, and set breakpoints to examine the values of variables at runtime

Comment: I'm guessing that titles.get(0) evaluates to null. But your code doesn't show where titles is declared, or initialised.

Comment: I already examined the value of titles.get(0), and it is indeed null.

Comment: It is initialized at the top of the MainActivity class:
private ArrayList<TextView> titles = new ArrayList<TextView>();

Comment: When I have textView id inside the main_activity.xml, I have no issues.
But that textView should be part of schedule_layout.xml, not main_activity.xml.

Comment: You need to show the code for MainActivity.java

Comment: Added the whole xml of activity_main as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84740/discussion-between-wilhelm-sorban-and-andrew-fielden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is quite straightforward:

Since I do

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_layout, container, false);
```

I add the "schedule_layout" to the rootView, so basically, when I do

```
titles.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView));
```

I tell the program to grab the textView from the main_activity layout, and since there is none, it returns null.

So I need to tell it to get it from schedule_layout, by:

```
titles.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView));
```